# Toggling sibling elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, siblings

I want to toggle the next sibling of a link in a list like this,

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a>
        <ul class="selected">
            <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a>
        <ul class="selected">
            <li><a href="#">4.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this is my jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a").each(function () {
        if ( $(this).siblings().size() > 0) 
        {
            $(this).append("<span class='has-child'>has child</span>");

            $(this).toggle(
                function (){
                    $("ul").removeClass("showme");
                    $(this).siblings(".selected").addClass("showme");
                    //$(this).next().css({display: "block"});
                },
                function (){
                    $(this).siblings(".selected").removeClass("showme");
                    //$(this).next().css({display: "none"});
            });

        }
    });
    
    $('ul > li > ul > li:last-child > a').css('background','yellow');
    
});
```

the css,

```
ul > li > ul {
        display:none;
    }
    
    ul > li:hover ul{
        display: block;
    }
    .showme {
        display: block;
    }
```

first of all, it seems fine - I can toggle the targeted sibling, but why after the first toggle at any parent, I have to click twice sometime to hide other siblings when I click/ toggle at the current parent?

here is the live site if I am not explaining it clearly,
http://lauthiamkok.net/tmp/jquery/toggle/

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function which is ending up in the wrong state you ca just use a normal `click` function and use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead, like this:

```
$(this).click(function (){
  var myUL = $(this).siblings(".selected").toggleClass("showme");
  $("ul").not(myUL).removeClass("showme");
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/29j3e/1/), this does a [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) on the sibling, then looks for all *other* `<ul>` elements, by filtering out the sibling with [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

This cleans up a bit making it easier, the main issue it resolves is the non-exclusion of the sibling from [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), this is what caused your [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) state to be incorrect before.

Comment: thanks u so much! i had completely forgotten about .toggleClass()!

it works perfectly now :-)))

Comment: sorry i have to come back to u for the same problem...

I just realised that the current parent does not toggle anymore, it only toggle when I click on other parents... have a look here,

http://lauthiamkok.net/tmp/jquery/toggle/index_1.html

for instance, when I click on the link 2 only, I was hoping to show its sibling too. and hide it when I click on this parent again.

is it possible...?


thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See the modified function. Just one change and it will work fine.

```
$("a").each(function () {
    if ( $(this).siblings().size() > 0) 
    {
        $(this).append("<span class='has-child'>has child</span>");

        $(this).toggle(
            function (){
                // $("ul").removeClass("showme"); Change this
                $(this).next("ul").removeClass("showme");
                $(this).siblings(".selected").addClass("showme");
                return false;
                //$(this).next().css({display: "block"});
            },
            function (){
                $(this).siblings(".selected").removeClass("showme");
                return false;
                //$(this).next().css({display: "none"});
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: still having the problem with this suggestion... but i have changed the code to as Nick suggested above,

$(this).click(function (){
    var myUL = $(this).siblings(".selected").toggleClass("showme");
    $("ul").not(myUL).removeClass("showme");
    return false;
   });